# Require class from another file in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify

I have a generic "main.js" and I want to get a class from another file. Here's what I have so far

**Structure**

```
main.js
/js
  /src
    menu.js
```

**main.js**

```
// main.js
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
require('./js/src/menu.js');

function run() {
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Menu), document.getElementById('menu'));
}

var loadedStates = ['complete', 'loaded', 'interactive'];

if (loadedStates.includes(document.readyState) && document.body) {
  run();
} else {
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run, false);
}
```

**menu.js** (Edited for brevity)

```
//menu.js
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var Menu = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        //do things
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, at the end of it all, I get
`Uncaught ReferenceError: Menu is not defined`

I'm using browserify to compile(?) everything into a bundle.js elsewhere in the project structure

Comment: in `menu.js` do you have `module.exports = Menu`? http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to store required menu.js object in a variable and in menu.js export its object so that other modules can access it.

in main.js

```
var Menu = require('./js/src/menu.js');
```

and in menu.js at the end of file.

```
module.exports = Menu;
```

Comment: You are mixing Common modules and ES6 modules... This will work with Babel afaik, but it is unclear why you'd mix both.

Answer (score 2):

You have to export what you want to require:

```
// menu.js
module.exports = Menu;

// main.js
// This path should be relative to the current file
var Menu = require('./js/src/menu.js');
```

Comment: tried this and got the following

```Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).```

---AND---

```Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.```

admittedly an improvement, but doesn't seem to be working quite yet.

Comment: Try `React.render(Menu, ...`

Comment: Ah, I needed to add the module.exports to the end of the file